# Concrete ceiling in bathroom, already painted once and flaking

Tags: bathroom, concrete, ceiling

We removed the popcorn from the concrete ceiling in our bathroom and it got primed and painted. Paint flaked from the get go (not just in that room) but got really really bad over time. Peeling through the paint/primer up to concrete. Room had poor ventilation and was highly used.

Fan has been replaced. We are getting ready to reprime/paint. Finding conflicting info on what to do.

Last time, Zinsser Primecoat2 primer was used plus SW flat paint. Concrete is old so fully cured. Heat was not great at the time of the paint job (empty unit at 60-65 degrees F) and job was rushed between coats. (done in 1 day)

This time, I am wondering if I need to use a sealer then a primer and paint, a specialized waterproofing primer or a concrete adhesion primer.
I was told by someone else in the building to stay away from water based primer as they had less issues with oil based.
Anyone care to point me in the right direction? Old paint was removed, and concrete has been fully sanded.

I was considering the following:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-PREMIUM-1-Gal-Concrete-and-Masonry-Bonding-Primer-88001/100129649

https://www.sherwin-williams.com/homeowners/products/loxon-concrete-masonry-primersealer

https://www.kilz.com/concrete-coatings/kilz-bonding-primer

https://www.homedepot.com/p/KILZ-Original-1-Gal-White-Low-VOC-Oil-Based-Interior-Primer-Sealer-and-Stain-Blocker-10936/100131137

Comment: Is there a bathroom on the upper floor over yours? Is this is a new building? It sounds like the concrete is quite moist. If the water is not from the upper floor, you should try to keep the bathroom dry for a period of time. I don't quite agree with the oil-based paint suggestion, as the concrete needs to breathe to reduce the moisture/water content.

Comment: There is no bathroom upstairs no. it is a living room. The room gets super humid whe  used due to no window, little fan and high usage, we were running a dehumidifer when using it for the last 6 months. it has not been used for 2+ weeks so it is likely drying, we can run a dehumifier prior to painting as well. Any advice on products to use?

Comment: Would this be something to consider? https://www.homedepot.com/p/DRYLOK-1-gal-Clear-Interior-Exterior-Floor-and-Wall-Basement-and-Masonry-Waterproofer-20913/205079075